# Vuejs | Create intermediate component that uses one of the props and propagate all remaining stuff to <button> element

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2

Probably a duplicate but I'm having a hard time formulating the problem since I'm new to Vue.

In our codebase we have the recurring pattern of a button accompanied by a message depending on whether the button is disabled or not.
Here is a simplified (full context below) example of what I mean:

```html
    <button 
      :disabled="!canSayHello"
      style="background-color:red"
    >
      Hi!
    </button>
    <p v-if="canSayHello"> Ready to say hi! </p>
    
    <br>
    
    <button 
      :disabled="!canSayGoodbye"
      name="the-bye-bye-button"
    >
      Bye!
    </button>
    <p v-if="canSayGoodbye"> You can say goodbye now </p>
```

I want to create an intermediate component `clarified-button` so that I can do something like:

```html
    <clarified-button
      :disabled="!canSayHello"
      clarification="Ready to say hi!"
      style="background-color:red"
    >
      Hi!
    </clarified-button>
    
    <br>
    
    <clarified-button
      :disabled="!canSayGoodbye"
      clarification="You can say goodbye now"
      name="the-bye-bye-button"
    >
      Bye!
    </clarified-button>
```

The inner `button` element of `clarified-button` *should not receive* the `clarification` prop, should receive *all the remaining stuff* that is given to it (attributes, listeners, etc?) and should use the received `disabled` prop.
I'm guessing it would involve something like:

```html
<button
  /*
   *  everything except the clarification prop gets propagated
   */
>
  <slot></slot>
</button>
<p v-if="!disabled"> {{ clarification }} </p>
```

---

Here is an MWE of the base case if that helps you:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div>
  
    <button 
        :disabled="!canSayHello"
      style="background-color:red"
    >
      Hi!
    </button>
    <p v-if="canSayHello"> Ready to say hi! </p>
    
    <br>
    
    <button 
        :disabled="!canSayGoodbye"
      name="the-bye-bye-button"
    >
      Bye!
    </button>
    <p v-if="canSayGoodbye"> You can say goodbye now </p>
    
  </div>
  `,
  data: {
    canSayHello: false,
    canSayGoodbye: true,
  },
})
```

---

**Actual problem**

We are using `bootstrap-vue` and I need to show tooltips over disabled buttons.
However when a `b-button` is disabled its `b-tooltip` does not show up.
The docs give a workaround (https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/tooltip/#disabled-elements) but it results in two separate components as shown in the simplified example.
I'm trying to understand how to create reusable and augmented components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the following can do the trick:

```js
Vue.component('clarified-button', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <button v-bind="$attrs" v-on="$listeners" :disabled="disabled">
        <slot></slot>
      </button>
      <p v-if="!disabled">
        {{ clarification }}
      </p>
    </div>
  `,
  props: ['clarification', 'disabled']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
  <div>
    <clarified-button
      :disabled="!canSayHello"
      style="background-color:red"
      clarification="Ready to say hi!"
    >
      Hi!
    </clarified-button>
    
    <br>
    
    <clarified-button
      :disabled="!canSayGoodbye"
      name="the-bye-bye-button"
      clarification="You can say goodbye now"
    >
      Bye!
    </clarified-button>
  </div>
  `,
  data: {
    canSayHello: false,
    canSayGoodbye: true,
  },
});
```

Note that [style and class are not included in $attrs if you use vue2](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/attrs-includes-class-style.html#_2-x-behavior) so a full solution would need an extra bit of work.